# Difference between hardware before and after laptop clean up

Tags: linux, cpu, tampering

I recently took my laptop to get cleaned and I saved the output of the command `lshw` to make sure the hardware was not changed.

After I got it back, I ran the `lshw` command again and did a diff, and I found out there's a difference between the CPU's capacity. Previously it was 1GHz and now it became 800MHz. Should I be worried? There is no serial number for Intel's processor anymore, therefore I can't tell whether it was changed or not.

Here is the output of `lshw` before the clean up:

```
*-cpu

description: CPU
product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2820QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
vendor: Intel Corp.
physical id: 4
bus info: cpu@0
version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2820QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
serial: N/A
slot: N/A
 size: 1GHz
 capacity: 1GHz
width: 64 bits
clock: 100MHz
capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
```

And here's the output after the clean up:

```
*-cpu
description: CPU
product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2820QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
vendor: Intel Corp.
physical id: 4
bus info: cpu@0
version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2820QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
serial: N/A
slot: N/A
 size: 800MHz
 capacity: 800MHz
width: 64 bits
clock: 100MHz
capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
```

Comment: Sounds like you... got taken to the cleaners.

Comment: You would need to post the full output of lshw before and after. However, as noted by the 'close' votes, this really isn't the right site for this. Probably SuperUser.

Comment: What model of laptop? If it has a socketed CPU, then what almost certainly happened is that the "professional" to whom you took it swapped your 1GHz CPU with a slower, cheaper part, most likely with the intention of reselling the one they stole -- not that that last part matters, if you can prove they stole the part. It might be worth your time to call the "cleaner" and discuss the matter; knowing that you can prove what they did -- and that your next call, should they fail to satisfy will be to your local law enforcement agency -- might convince them to give you your part back.

Comment: The CPU model is the same, I wonder if its getting downthrottled

Comment: Yes @AaronMiller I thought so too, I'm going tomorrow to clear matters up, and update the question with what happened in case someone else had this same problem.

Comment: It sounds like the CPU is simply being downthrottled.  Its unlikely the CPU can even be changed very few laptops used a socketed CPU.  Its also unlikely that its socketed since its i7-2820QM which has not been on the market for years, its the first generation processor, its near worthless on the market.

Comment: @Ramhound I thought of that, but the clock is listed at 100MHz in both cases, which made it look unlikely. On the other hand, I suppose that could be the FSB clock or similar, and lshw reports the same actual part in both cases, so it may be that I've jumped the gun a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I ran the `yes | yes | yes | yes` command on a terminal for about a minute and then ran `lshw` in a different terminal and got 1GHz back. I ran `yes | yes | yes | yes` on two different terminals at the same time, and did `lshw` and got 2.3GHz.

I therefore concluded that this value scales with CPU utilization and it's not fixed.